# CodeEval / Sequence Transformation Code Timeout

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

The challenge description is here: https://www.codeeval.com/browse/130/

Two rules:

1. "0" can be transformed into non empty sequence of letters "A" ("A", "AA", "AAA" etc.)
2. "1" can be transformed into non empty sequence of letters "A" ("A", "AA", "AAA" etc.) or to non empty sequence of letters "B" ("B", "BB", "BBB" etc) e.g.

Test Cases:

1. 1010 AAAAABBBBAAAA          ==>        Yes
2. 00 AAAAAA                   ==>        Yes
3. 01001110 AAAABAAABBBBBBAAAAAAA      ==> Yes
4. 1100110 BBAABABBA          ==> No

The solution came to my mind was regular expression, and I implemented recursively. For small test cases above, it works fine. But when it comes to long strings, the code runs timeout for more than 10 seconds.

For example, the following case takes "forever" to get the result:

00111010000001000111010000101111110101110001001 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

There are even longer cases waiting to be tested.

Here are my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool validate(string pattern, int i, string text, int j);

bool matchA(string pattern, int i, string text, int j)
{
    while(j < text.size() && text[j] == 'A')
    {
        j++;
        if(validate(pattern, i+1, text, j))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool matchAB(string pattern, int i, string text, int j, char c)
{
    while(j < text.size() && text[j] == c)
    {
        j++;
        if(validate(pattern, i+1, text, j))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool validate(string pattern, int i, string text, int j)
{
    if(i == pattern.size())
        return j == text.size();
    if(pattern[i] == '0')
        return matchA(pattern, i, text, j);
    if(pattern[i] == '1')
        return matchAB(pattern, i, text, j, text[j]);
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string pattern = "00";
    string text = "AAAAA";
    if(validate(pattern, 0, text, 0))
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I prove the correctness of the code above (Ironically, I'm not very confident about the recursion I wrote)?
2. If the code is not right, how can I debug it?
3. Assuming my code is correct, it is obvious that recursion is not the best solution (too many backtracking), and I have a feeling to solve it by using DP. I've tried memoization to store the result of (i, j), but still failed. Need ideas to hack this problem.

Thanks for your time and comments!

Comment: Keep track of the states you could be in when reading each successive character of the second string. Define a recurrence relation to compute the states for character i from character i - 1.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for @jonderry's hint, here is the DP solution:

Assuming State[i,j] is used to save the state of the pattern[i] and text[j], if State[i,j] == true, we say from pattern[0] to pattern[i] and from text[0] to text[j], the sequence transformation is valid.
Therefore, we can compute the State[i,j] based on the following condition:

```
State[i,j] =
1. (pattern[i] == '0' and text[j] == 'A') or pattern[i] == '1'   // if State[i-1,j-1] = true
2. State[i-1,j] && text[j-1] == text[j],                         // otherwise
```

Thank you for your time and comments!